# gradiant colour for ng-2 line chart along y-axis

Tags: angular, canvas, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am using ng-2 charts in angular for a line chart.

My code

.html

```
  <canvas baseChart height="100" [chartType]="'line'" [datasets]="chartData" [labels]="labels"
              [options]="chartOptions" [legend]="false"></canvas>
```

.ts

```
chartData = [{
    fill: true,
    data: [21, 26, 24, 21, 25, 25, 27, 21, 29, 27, 24, 29],
    borderColor: 'blue  ',
    pointBackgroundColor: '00bfff   ',
    pointBorderColor: '00bfff   ',
    pointStyle: 'circle',
  }]

  labels = ['10 AM','10 AM','10 AM','10 AM','10 AM','10 AM','10 AM','10 AM','10 AM','10 AM','10 AM','10 AM']
```

I want the area under my chart to be filled in a gradient manner along the y-axis. Documentation talks how to do it along x-axis, but I want it along y-axis , something like
[image]

can someone help me this?